# Как понять работу array_reduce?

Tags: php, массивы

Кто может помочь разъяснить механизм работы функции array_reduce http://php.net/array_reduce

Я описание которое есть в доках "array_reduce() итеративно применяет callback-функцию callback к элементам массива array и, таким образом, сводит массив к единственному значению." вообще не понимаю.

Что значит "сводит" т.е. остальные значения отбрасываются? Принцип сведения тоже не понятен, какое он оставляет, наибольшее, наименьшее и почему?

Например в коде ниже:

```
$array = array(
1, 2, 'tom', '7jerry', 010, '020'
);
$callback = function ($a, $b) {
return $a + intval($b);
};
echo array_reduce($array, $callback, 1);
```

Ответ будет 39, но почему и как он получается - непонятно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем колбеке `$a` - суммарное значение, `$b` - текущий элемент. Сама операция функции у вас `return $a + intval($b);` добавляет к текущей сумме значение `$b` приведённое к `int`'у. Сама же функция `array_reduce` применяет ваш колбек к каждому элементу и аккумулирует итоговое значение.

По шагам:

```
   a     b
1) 1     1 
2) 2     2 
3) 4     tom 
4) 4     7jerry 
5) 11    8 
6) 19    020
```

Тут небольшой конфуз может быть только с `7jerry` - оно при попытке получить `int` выдаст 7. Поэтому на 5 шаге сумма будет равна 11.

После всех шагов в итоге будет 39.

Comment: То что 7jerry к 7 приведётся я знал. А вот про 020 интереснее. Это ведь восьмеричная система исчисления? Но int число привёл к двоичной просто отбросив первый 0? Т.е. выходит что в данном случае array_reduce выступает суммой всех элементов т.к. в коллбек-функции задан суммировнаие, я верно понял?

Comment: @RoboNoob в данном случае да, это просто сумма всех значений.